What is this SMD 6-pins LED controlling component?
I want to build a similar, simple circuit that is switch activated blinking/flashing one or two LEDs, then it turn off automatically in about 10 seconds.

What the name of the component in this image that make the effect that I want?
Here is the circuit, 2 LEDs (equal size as 3528 LED) and??



I want to keep the circuit samall and simple. How can I archive the same result with other components?



Did you remove the potting? It's some ASIC or microcontroller.

@Unimportant No, I did not, it is original, I have another version that is covered in potting too.

Apparantly some manufacturer found it cheaper or simpler to package the controller die in a LED like package. I've not seen that before. Still, it's just some microcontroller or similar...

Thank for the suggestion and the link, at least I am not the only one who questioning about this tiny thing.

Probably the LED maker bought ASIC dies from a supplier, and packaged them in the SMD lead frame they already using to manufacture addressable LEDs (which incorporate an ASIC die and several LED dies).
A case of using what is inexpensive and at-hand to make a new product.
In China the LED makers often get their LED dies (and ASICs) from 3rd party suppliers. There are many makers of ASIC dies and packaged ICs that perform simple functions for things like PWM flashlights and so on.
For example, here is an IC designed for applications like the alternating red/blue epaulette lights that Chinese traffic officers often wear at night. The characters (执勤) say "on duty".


It seem like this is not a thing that I can buy from a marketplace.

@TinThai It may or may not be, but less likely in that package, and it may be challenging to find, even if you can read Chinese, and it may be difficult to complete a transaction for a small quantity.

Thank you, your answer shows me the right direction.
